# Array of Any call function append.contentsOf syntax error in Swift 3.2

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, syntax

```
var dataSource: [Any] = []
```

I declare array like above, then when I do

```
// fetchedData is an array of Swift object
dataSource.append(contentsOf: fetchedData)
```

I am have compile error saying `Extraneous argument label 'contentsOf:' in call`
The `[Any]` type thinks I am passing a single object, I don't prefer to change the dataSource type to a specific one. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: try putting `append(contentsOf: fetchedData as [Any])

Comment: Consider to use something more specific than `Any`.

Comment: Echoing @vadian's point, there is almost no case where `[Any]` is the correct type. You are almost certainly approaching the problem incorrectly, and while it's possible to work around this (as in Julien's answer), you will likely fight Swift constantly if you continue down this road. `Any` is not a general-use type; it's for very specialized problems and difficult to use correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use `append(contentsOf:)` with an array of the exact same element type than the array you're appending to. It means it will only work if `dataSource` is of type `[Any]`. You can fix that by using

```
append(contentsOf: fetchedData as [Any])
```

---

Now the reason why you see this wierd error "Extraneous argument label 'contentsOf:' in call" is because even though in your code `fetchedData` does not qualify as `[Any]`, it qualifies as `Any`, which means you could technically use the other append (`append(_ newElement: Any)`), to add `fetchData` as a single element and create a two-level array. Swift thinks you want to do this and, in order to make it work like this, you would have to remove the argument "contentsOf".